# Best way to pass latitude and longitude as props in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-props

I'm trying to include a google map for a certain geographical location in my app. The location can change and so can't be hard coded.

My Map component is as follows (irrelevant stuff removed):

```
import React from 'react';

class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lat: this.props.selectedVenue.lat,
      lng: this.props.selectedVenue.lng,
      zoom: 13,
      maptype: 'Satellite”',      
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng },
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    });

  }

  render() {
    console.log("this.props.selectedVenue.lat", this.props.selectedVenue.lat);
    console.log("this.props.selectedVenue.lng", this.props.selectedVenue.lng);    
    return (
      <div id='app'>
        <div id='map' />
      </div>
    ); 
  } 
}

export default Map;
```

When I hard code the value into the state of Map.js everything works fine and the map appears. However, when I use the method above, I'm left with a blank map. The values are coming through but the console tells me:

"InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number"

I've tried using Number() to ensure it's actually a number, Math.round to make sure that it's not something to do with the number of digits and have tried bypassing state altogether and just passing the prop directly in but with no luck. I've tried searching on here but where the question has been asked there haven't been any satisfactory answers (happy to be corrected if I'm wrong on this).

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

*** edit / additional ***

this.props.selectedVenue is originally set in the state of the grandparent component (App.js) when a venue is searched for. The returned selection of venues are stored in the state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {
  ...
  venues : [],
  selectedVenue : []
  ...
}

this.search = this.search.bind(this);
this.populateSelectedVenue = this.populateSelectedVenue.bind(this);
```

}

```
  search(term) { 
    this.setState({
      ...
      venues : [],
      selectedVenue : [],
      ...
    })

    APIVenues.getVenues(term).then(res => { // getVenues
      this.setState({venues: res});
    });
  }
```

and another method is used to set this.state.selectedVenues with the appropriate venue:

```
  populateSelectedVenue = (venue) => { concat
    this.setState({selectedVenue: venue});
  }
```

populateSelectedVenue is passed as a prop to another component where it is triggered by an onClick and the appropriate venue passed into it.

Comment: What do you see in console if you add following log just at the beginning of componentDidMount()

`console.log({lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng })`

Comment: Have just edited the question as I missed some stuff out. Console says: "InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number". selectedVenue is passed as props from the parent component and contains all the venue details including lat and lng.

Comment: Is the `selectedVenue` passed in to your `Map` loaded when `Map` is created? It might be that `selectedVenue` is asynchronously loaded, and you don't get the proper values to your constructor.

Comment: Can you comment out let map = ..... block 
and just log `console.log({lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng })` inside componentDidMount. Then you will see what's wrong.

Comment: Chathura: Adding the console.log as suggested returns: Object { lat: undefined, lng: undefined } Tholle: that might be it... but not sure how to remedy it. Maybe a setState?

Comment: So that is the issue... At the time you create Map object, those values are undefined.

Comment: Thanks - any idea how to sort that out?

Comment: How do you resolve selectedVenue in parent component? If you can post the code of parent component, we will be able to give you a solution. Or simply don't render Map component until parent fully resolve all the values of selectedVenue object.

Comment: Will do an edit - 1 sec... just need to find the relevant stuff to include. Thanks.

Comment: The code is not clear,please mention where populateSelectedVenue() is called.

Comment: I'm trying to cut out confusing stuff here. the search methoid in App.js triggers an object which goes to the foursquare api. That returns a list of venues and passes them to a component called renderVenues. This maps them to instances of another component RenderVenueItems which is where populateSelectedVenue() is triggered by an onClick. This passes the relevant venue back to App.js where this.state.selectedVenue is populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method in your `Map` component. This method will be called **every time** all the props passed to your component changed.

So, the solution is:

1. In `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, new a google map Object with a `default` latitude and longitude using state value, and set the new `map` object above to be a member variable in `Map` component, just for keep the reference of the object.

   `componentDidMount() {
       this.map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: { lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng },
         zoom: 13,
         mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
       });
   }`
2. In `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` lifecycle method, set the map center using `nextProps` argument.

   `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if (nextProps.selectedVenue.lat !== this.props.selectedVenue.lat
           || nextProps.selectedVenue.lng !== this.props.selectedVenue.lng) {
           this.map.setCenter({lat: nextProps.selectedVenue.lat, lng: nextProps.selectedVenue.lng});
       }
   }`

Comment: Genius... thank you ;-) Now I just need to sit down and work out WHY it works :D